# Struggling to plot a curve in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I'm making a couple of ggplot graphs with some [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LxQh-d34zkfQjZjLyi9t2FjBx1WWJc83q84YBBUfxZU/edit?usp=sharing) I've been given on UV mutagenesis of some bacteria. I'm trying to fit a curve to the second graph (time vs % survival) I don't think it likes the fact that there's only 3 data points resulting from the fact you don't count plates with <30 / >300 colonies. So when plotting the curve twists towards the final datapoint, however in reality, it would continue to downward trend towards 0%

```r
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.csv("uv_mutagenesis.csv")

# Filter <30 / >300
filtered_data <- data %>%
  filter(colonies_per_plate >= 30, colonies_per_plate <= 300)


#mean, SD, SEM
mean_data <- filtered_data %>%
  group_by(time, dilution) %>%
  summarize(mean_colonies = mean(colonies_per_plate),
            sd_colonies = sd(colonies_per_plate),
            sem_colonies = sd(colonies_per_plate) / sqrt(n()))

# CFU/ml
plated_volume_ml <- 1
mean_data$CFU_per_ml <- mean_data$mean_colonies / (mean_data$dilution * plated_volume_ml)

# Plot CFU/ml vs time
ggplot(mean_data, aes(x = time, y = CFU_per_ml, theme_bw())) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = CFU_per_ml - sem_colonies / (mean_data$dilution * plated_volume_ml),
                    ymax = CFU_per_ml + sem_colonies / (mean_data$dilution * plated_volume_ml)),
                width = 0.05) + 
  labs(x = "Time",
       y = "CFU/ml")


# Calculate percentage spore survival
unirradiated_data <- mean_data %>%
  filter(time == 0) %>%
  select(dilution, CFU_per_ml)


percentage_survival_data <- mean_data %>%
  left_join(unirradiated_data, by = "dilution") %>%
  mutate(percentage_survival = (CFU_per_ml.x / CFU_per_ml.y) * 100) %>%
  select(-CFU_per_ml.y) %>%
  mutate(percentage_survival = pmin(percentage_survival, 100))

#Plot % survival vs time 

ggplot(percentage_survival_data, aes(x = time.x, y = percentage_survival, theme_bw())) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  labs(x = "Time",
       y = "Percentage Survival")
```

[image]

Should look something more like the curves here:
[image]

any ideas on how I can fix this.

```r
structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16), colonies_per_plate = c(141L, 
75L, 120L, 126L, 102L, 113L, 101L, 102L, 121L, 10L, 14L, 12L, 
12L, 21L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), dilution = c(1e-09, 1e-09, 
1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 1e-09, 
1e-09, 1e-08, 1e-08, 1e-08, 1e-08, 1e-08, 1e-08, 1e-06, 1e-06, 
1e-06), plated_volume_ml = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO @jos mackinnon! I'd like to help but I'm not entirely sure I understand what is the problem you wish to fix. Can you clarify? Additionally, once the problem is clearer, it'll be very helpful if you can provide data (viz., `dput(data)`) sufficient to minimally reproduce that problem.

Comment: Hi @RKeithL so basically, I want the curve as it slopes down to just continue downward through the third point on the graph not curve towards, can you access the data I linked in the first paragraph?

Comment: if all you want is a straight line then it should be as simple as using `geom_smooth(method = 'lm')`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: As a matter of SO customs, it is preferred to post code rather than simply link to it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Doing so will typically get you quality help more quickly. Cheers!

Comment: sorry first time on here, I've added the data, not sure what all the "L"s are. no 'lm' doesn't work, I want it to curve down from the datapoint at (0.5, 100) and pass through the last data point. I think it may be an issue that I don't have enough datapoints to visualise a proper trend for R to make its calculations off

Comment: Don't worry--the Ls belong! Someone smarter than me may come along and say otherwise, but yea my sense (if you do not desire straight line) is that it's prob due to so few datapoints. Could you add a few dummy points to test it?

Comment: @josmackinnon I think the upward curve occurs because you were not including the dilution information. There's no upward blip when you adjust for dilution.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I've worked out what I need to do. Thank you for all taking the time and bearing with my lack of SO understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack ofdescription of the experimental details prevents understanding what is actually going on. Are we irradiating three separate beakers of broth with UV radiation and then taking samples at changing dilutions over times at irregular intervals? Is this actually a repeated measures sort of experiment that should be illustrated with these graphs? (This is what I think is where the "real" problem lies: less with the plotting details and more with the underlying scientific reality.)

I'll post an "old school" R answer with the `lattice` package. By not collapsing the data into means we can see the individual points in all their random glory. One needs to take into account the change in dilution by dividing the counts by the dilution value:

```
library(lattice)
#make a repetition identifier
df1$rep <- 1:3  # will be recycled
png(); xyplot( colonies_per_plate/dilution ~ time, group=rep, 
               data=df1, 
               scales=list(y=list(log="e")))
dev.off()
```

[image]

The virtues of this approach: does less trauma to the data by not taking means of data within reps, uses both counts and dilution information in proper biologic fashion, and illustrates exponential relationship well with straight line results on log plot. I do think it properly mimics the illustration's graphical "behavior" since it also used a log scale. It shouldn't be too difficult to construct the same behavior with `ggplot` code, now that I have demonstrated what transformations are needed to make biologic sense out of this.

Looking at the curve: it's possible that there is sort of Weibull survival curve hiding under this. It might be fun to see if there were statistical support for a more complex survival curve added to this but the number of data points makes me think the level of statistical support might be "thin".

Could also experiment with adding a tasty (linear) regression line

```
xyplot( colonies_per_plate/dilution ~ time, group=rep, data=df1, scales=list(y=list(log="e")), 
      panel = function(x,y) { panel.lmline(x,y); 
                              panel.points(x,y)})
```

...Or leave the log transform out ... which really screws things up :-)

```
xyplot( colonies_per_plate/dilution ~ time, group=rep, data=df1, 
            panel = function(x,y) { panel.lmline(x,y); 
                                    panel.points(x,y)})
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I misunderstood the task myself, and have just gone and plotted a straight line over it. Thank you so much for taking the time to try and fix the issue though!